# Constructor and inheriting properties from super class in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a question about a code demonstrating inheritance in javascript.
The code is based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

You can see live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/gk6xar8w/3/

Here's the code:

```js
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 1;
  this.y = 2;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.',this.x,this.y);
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
  console.log("###### Inside Rectangle.constructor ######");
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

//If you don't set Rectangle.prototype.constructor to Rectangle,
//it will take the prototype.constructor of Shape (parent).
//To avoid that, we set the prototype.constructor to Rectangle (child).
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 2); // Outputs, 'Shape moved. 2, 4'
rect.move(1, 2); // Outputs, 'Shape moved. 3, 6'
```

I have two questions.

Firstly, I'm not sure what the effect of `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle` is. Even when I comment this line out, I still get same output. To help me understand I am logging "#### Inside Rectangle.constructor #####" inside `function Rectangle() {...}`. But this logs even when I comment out `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle`.

Secondly, last two lines which both are `rect.move(1, 2)`, they don't behave as I expected. First invocation outputs `2, 4` and the second outputs `3, 6`.

We start with `this.x = 1` and `this.y = 2` defined inside parent class. First time we invoke `rect.move(1,2)` it adds for x: `1+1=2` and y: `2+2=4` as expected. But second time around, it doesn't x: `2+2=4` and y: `4+4=8` as expected. Instead it keeps the initial values of `this.x = 1` and `this.y = 2` and does x: `1+2=3` and y: `2+4=6`.

It would be great if I can fix the code so that first invocation of `rect.move(1,2)` outputs `2, 4` and second invocation ouputs `4, 8` and third outputs `8, 16` and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Both times, you're asking it to move `(1, 2)`. I'm not sure why you expect the results to be different

Comment: I want to do multiple moves and values of x and y to persist. If we do move(1,2) more than once they give different values in this case.

Comment: To answer your first question, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: The values of `x` and `y` **are** persisting. Break it down; start with `x: 1, y: 2`, then add `(1, 2)` so that's `x: 1 + 1 = 2` and `y: 2 + 2 = 4`. The values are now `x: 2, y: 4`. Then add `(1, 2)` again so it's `x: 2 + 1 = 3` and `y: 4 + 2 = 6`

Comment: yeh, i know but that's not strictly what i was expecting.

Comment: I'll ask again, why would you expect them to be different? Please edit your question to explain what you think they should be and why you think that

Comment: If you want the subsequent invocations to output `(4, 8)` then `(8, 16)`, you would need to move by larger amounts each time, ie `rect.move(1, 2); rect.move(2, 4); rect.move(4, 8)`

Comment: @Phil sorry about the confusion. I get it now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your first question, `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle` has no effect. That line sets the constructor of the Rectangle class but the `Rectangle()` function is already the constructor, so there is no effect.

For your second question, the move function changes the x value of the object by the x value passed into the function. Same goes for the y value. 2+1=3 and 4+2=6

If you want the x and y values to double each time, you could use this function:

```
Shape.prototype.move = function() {
    this.x += this.x; // <-- uses this.x instead of x parameter
    this.y += this.y; // <-- uses this.y instead of y parameter
    console.info('Shape moved.',this.x,this.y);
};
```

Comment: What's the point in passing in `x` and `y` values to `move` if they're never used?

Comment: Right. They should probably be removed then

Answer (score 0):

I understand now.

```js
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 1;
  this.y = 2;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function() {
  this.x += this.x;
  this.y += this.y;
  console.info('Shape moved.',this.x,this.y);
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
  console.log("###### Inside Rectangle.constructor ######");
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

//If you don't set Rectangle.prototype.constructor to Rectangle,
//it will take the prototype.constructor of Shape (parent).
//To avoid that, we set the prototype.constructor to Rectangle (child).
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
rect.move(); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

This outputs 1,2 -> 2,4 -> 4,8 -> ... and requires no arguments to move().

In the original code, `this.x` and `this.y` persist. Sorry for the confusion and thanks a lot.

Here's a working code:

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 1;
  this.y = 2;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(a) {
  this.x = this.x + a;
  this.y = this.y + a;
  console.info('Shape moved.',this.x,this.y);
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
  console.log("###### Inside Rectangle.constructor ######");
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

//If you don't set Rectangle.prototype.constructor to Rectangle,
//it will take the prototype.constructor of Shape (parent).
//To avoid that, we set the prototype.constructor to Rectangle (child).
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(3); // x: 4, y: 5
rect.move(3); // x: 7, y: 8
rect.move(3); // x: 10, y: 11
```

Note that `this.x` and `this.y` are persistent.